# strace and polkit

Tags: sudo, privileges, strace

I have a program who refuse to run as root, he wants the "true user" to run it, but he wants privilege escalation during the execution to modify some protected paths

With `strace` it's okay as long as I don't invoke the `-f` argument, but when I need it the polkit window doesn't appear and the program complains about not having privileges and just ends

---

I don't really know what is a setUID but the command is `$ strace -f script.bash`

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the arguments you're passing to `strace`? More specifically, are you tracing the setuid program, or are you tracing a program that calls the setuid program? And is the setuid program `pkexec`, or is it something else?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Does `script.bash` run `pkexec` ?

Comment: If this is an execution so yeah `read -n 1 -r -s reply
        if [[ $reply == [Yy] ]]; then
                "pkexec" "$NAME_INST" "$@"` but i'm really not sure because it's executed in a further step and if I am executing without GUI and I am in neither cases

Comment: That makes sense. Last question: what is it that you need to trace? The "$NAME_INST" program? Some other program that it calls?

Comment: I want to know every files that he modifies/create, because the deinstallation program does not clean everything that it gets into, so I want to observe it. In a second time I want too to know what files he reads to gather informations

Answer (score 1):

Strace uses the [ptrace](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) system call to trace processes.

For security reasons, a privileged program such as pkexec, which uses the [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) mechanism, cannot use those privileges if the process tracing it is not root (or, on Linux, does not have the `SYS_PTRACE` or `SYS_ADMIN`
[capability](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).)

When you run `strace script.bash`, strace will successfully trace the shell that runs the script - which doesn't have any extra privileges - and will not trace any programs that the shell script runs. So when the script runs `pkexec`, pkexec runs with all privileges.

But `strace -f script.bash` will trace the shell that runs the script *and every program run by the script*. When the script runs `pkexec`, pkexec won't have setuid privileges, and it will complain and exit.

One way to trace pkexec and everything it runs is to run strace as root.

But you don't want to run `sudo strace -f script.bash`, because that will run the script (and pkexec) as root.

Instead, have strace attach to the script after you've started the script as a regular user. Modify the script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo please run sudo strace -f -p $$ while this script is doing its read
read -n 1 -r -s reply
if [[ $reply == [Yy] ]]; then
    pkexec "$NAME_INST" "$@"
fi
```